# My site at another domain

Tags: proxy, website

Yesterday i found another site that use my content i mean not just content it's a full my site... something like they using proxy and display all from mysite, any changes i make, this is displayed on another domain

I just checked IP and they don't use my ip, but there is any chance to protect this... im on apache, dedicated server with dedicated IP....

i was try to make something in php for example
if(&_SERVER[HTTP_HOST] != 'mysite.com'){redirect.....}

But later i was checked and they have also same [HTTP_HOST] as my site...

Comment: Is the other domain just pointing to your host and you are serving the content yourself?

Comment: Yes i think... they is just pointed to my server and display my site to their domain...

Comment: Then configure your web server to don't do this - you need to make the default site something not showing your content. E.g. http://serverfault.com/questions/495927/setup-default-page-for-apache-virtual-hosts

Comment: I already make config, but problem is still there
this is something like this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250916/what-is-stackoverflow-com-80bola-com

Comment: Please make it clear what problem you face. Having a site proxying your content is something different than having a 3rd party domain pointing to your web server. If you can't find out the difference yourself, you shouldn't operate the server in the first place.

Comment: My fault I'm not explained situation... yes 3rd party domain pointing to my  server and all what i need is to block it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is create a vhost for the third party domain name and then return whatever data you want to it.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName thirdparty.example.com
    ServerAlias *.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/thirdparty
</VirtualHost>
```

Now you can send anything you want back to them.

Comment: I was try this method with vhost but does not working, i was try now with php and this trick is working, but it's not what i need....`if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REAL_IP'] == '62.210.181.99'){header('Location: http://google.com/');}`

Answer (score 1):

Iain's answer is technically correct. However, from your current set up, it seems like your site is actually on the default configuration and is answering *all* requests to your server. You can double check this by simply typing in your IP address, instead of the domain, in any browser. If your site still shows up, then it is the default site.

When you set up Virtual Hosts, Apache answers them in the order presented. Therefore, you need to put Iain's code as the *first* host in your Apache configuration.

If your Apache configuration uses split files, you can disable the default host, and move your site to an individual virtual host. Then, the order of VHosts does not matter, as long as no domains or server aliases overlap.

Comment: In a correctly configured name based virtual host system order shouldn't matter unless you're not matching the host header correctly in a ServerName or ServerAlias at which point, yes the default (first defined) vhost gets served.

Comment: According to Apache docs, "If the client provided a Host: header field the list is searched for a matching vhost and **the first hit on a ServerName or ServerAlias is taken** and the request is served from that host." From that, I believe that Apache actually treat's the default VHost's Server Name (if it's a wildcard) to match everything?

Comment: ServerName can't be a wildcard. But you're right ServerAlias could be `*` and that might throw a spanner of misconfiguration n the works.

Comment: Yep! That's what I meant! But, like you said, that's a terrible and unnecessary configuration.